# Single voltage replacement for 741 opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative

I am working on a project that recreates the cassette-in port on an Apple II for use in an Apple IIGS. The original circuit used the LM741. The location where I am interfacing my circuit only has +5V and GND. The audio is decoded using a zero crossing detector. Would a single supply opamp like an LM358 be a suitable replacement?

[image: Apple II Cassete-In Interface]

Comment: It seems strange that this circuit uses positive feedback. Is this the circuit actually used in the Apple II? Basically this circuit just acts as a Schmitt trigger, not really an amplifier.

Comment: A schmitt trigger sounds reasonable.  This is the cassette in, which is used to read digital data from an audio cassette.  A schmitt trigger was often used to improve the reliability when reading from tape.

Comment: It's using the 741 as a comparator with hysteresis (ie its a schmitt trigger). Using a true comparator such as an LM339 may be a better replacement.

Comment: You could probably directly use an RS-485 receiver (built-in hysteresis that is similar, single supply, and input common mode range that goes below ground).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substituting a single-supply opamp can work just fine if you make some modifications to the circuit. One of the most straightforward ways to adapt from a bipolar supply to a single supply is to reference the original GND to a "virtual GND" that is 1/2 of your supply rail.

This circuit below illustrates the point. The simulation was done in LTspice, available of free charge. Hope that helps.

[image: LTspice schematic and simulation of Apple II tape interface]

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation and schematic.  Am I correct in assuming V1 would be my input?

Comment: Yup, V1 in the simulation is the input signal from your cassette player. Interesting aside: As a kid, I started learning to program on an Atari 400. We didn't have the money for the Atari cassette recorder. I reverse-engineered my friends recorder and built a replica circuit onto a homebuilt perfboard to interface to my Dad's tape recorder. It had same front end as your circuit, 2 active filters for tone decoding and a comparator for output. All done with LM324 quad opamp. I learned a lot doing that project :) Good luck on your Apple IIgs interface!